# Burn MKV with subtitles on a DVD

Tags: mkv, freeware

I have a movie on an mkv file, the movie has video, audio and the subtitles all in the mkv file but I cannot find a way to burn it to dvd including the subtitles. I need to get VIDEO_TS and AUDIO_TS files out of the mkv file so I can burn those on dvd with a program like ImgBurn.

Please tell me which program I can use to get those VIDEO_TS and AUDIO_TS files (including working subtitles) out of my MKV file, I would like to keep the quality the MKV file has, and I need a program that is 100% free, I don't want a free trial.

I am using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/), it's 100% free and you can just burn MKV files on dvd, on the dvd, the subtitles also work if you set that up properly in the [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/) program.

Comment: It is not free. You have to pay to remove the watermak.